# Field "features" does not exist. SparkML

Tags: scala, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to build a model in Spark ML with Zeppelin.
I am new to this area and would like some help. I think i need to set the correct datatypes to the column and set the first column as the label. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

```
val training = sc.textFile("hdfs:///ford/fordTrain.csv")
val header = training.first
val inferSchema = true  
val df = training.toDF

val lr = new LogisticRegression()
.setMaxIter(10)
.setRegParam(0.3)
.setElasticNetParam(0.8)

 val lrModel = lr.fit(df)

// Print the coefficients and intercept for multinomial logistic regression
println(s"Coefficients: \n${lrModel.coefficientMatrix}")
println(s"Intercepts: ${lrModel.interceptVector}")
```

A snippet of the csv file i am using is:

```
IsAlert,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,E1,E2
0,34.7406,9.84593,1400,42.8571,0.290601,572,104.895,0,0,0,
```

Comment: what version of spark are you using ?

Comment: Hi, Im working in hortonworks sandbox. Multiple versions of Spark are installed but SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is not set
Spark1 will be picked by default. The default is 1.6.3

Comment: I'd suggest taking look at the [example provided in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/ml-classification-regression.html#logistic-regression) for your version of Spark. In there is states that you can "Find full example code at "examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/LogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample.scala" in the Spark repo."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you are missing the `features` column. It is a vector containing all predictor variables. You have to create it using `VectorAssembler`.

`IsAlert` is the label and all others variables (p1,p2,...) are predictor variables, you can create `features` column (actually you can name it anything you want instead of `features`) by:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

//creating features column
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("P1","P2","P3","P4","P5","P6","P7","P8","E1","E2"))
  .setOutputCol("features")


val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
  .setFeaturesCol("features")   // setting features column
  .setLabelCol("IsAlert")       // setting label column

//creating pipeline
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler,lr))

//fitting the model
val lrModel = pipeline.fit(df)
```

Refer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler.